# How to multiplying two polynomials using dictionary in python?

Tags: python

```
p = {1:2,0:-1}
q = {1:1,0:2}
```

`p` in polynomial form is 2x-1. `q` is x+2. The answer of this will be 2x^2+x-2 in the dictionary form is `v = {2:2,1:1,0:2}` The output dictionary form is the answer, however, the code is not giving the correct result.

```
 def polynomial(p,q):
     v = {}
     for key1,value1 in p.items():
         for key2,value2 in q.items():
             key = key1 + key2
             value = value1 * value2
             v[key] = value
     return v
```

I know this code is only calculating Ax^2 and C in Ax^2+Bx+C. One thing I know how to do is what we will use in list -> `key[1] + key[2]` , however, is there way I can do this in dictionary?

Comment: was there a typo? `f` and `g` are in fact `p` and `q` right?

Comment: the typo of `f`,`g` is `p`,`q`, the question is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating each term in the polynomial, you are replacing it.
Instead of `v[key] = value`, use:

```py
if key in v:
   v[key] += value
else:
   v[key] = value
```